# Why am I not able to properly use str.replace() method in python

Tags: python, string, replace, autofill

This is my first time posting here and if I am posting incorrectly please let me know. I have read a lot of the threads here and info on other website. They all say string are immutable and I understand that but I am trying to use the `str.replace()` method in my autofill function and I can't seem to get it down properly. Is it not possible at all? here's my code:

```
def main():

    fileName = input("Please enter a filename: ") 

    file = open(fileName, 'r')  # opens the file
    content = file.readlines()  # reads in the contents as a list

    x=0                         # x is a random variable used for while loop   
    while x < (len(content)-1): # while loop is used to remove the "\n" at the end
        content[x] = content[x].strip() #strip method is used to remove \n
        x=x+1                   # adds 1 to x to help stop the loop

    printBoard(content)

    move = selection()

    while move != "q" :
        row = (int(move[0]))-1
        column = (int(move[3])) -1

        content = autoFill(content, row, column)

        printBoard(content)

        move = selection()

def autoFill(board, rows, columns):

    if (board[rows][columns]) == 'X' :
        return (board)
    board[rows][columns] = ((board[rows][columns]).replace('O', 'X'))
    print(board)

    return (board)
```

here's a sample run of what should happen:

```
Please enter a filename: input.txt
OOOOOOXOOOO
OOOOOXOOOOO
OOOOXOOOOOO
XXOOXOOOOOO
XXXXOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOO
Please enter a square to fill, or q to exit: 1, 1
XXXXXXXOOOO
XXXXXXOOOOO
XXXXXOOOOOO
XXXXXOOOOOO
XXXXOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOO
```

but when i run it. none of the Os change to X as a result my recursion function goes on forever(well until runtime crashes)

Comment: What did you expect the replace to do? What happened instead? What inputs are you giving your `autoFill` function?

Comment: You rebound `board` to the `str.replace()` return value; a new string object. Did you expect the function to return the whole board instead?

Comment: So it's a board full of Os and Xs and I expected the replace function to change the O to an X.

Comment: sorry I mistakenly submitted my test code. But I just wanted to replace that 1 index in from the list.

Comment: Then it is still not clear what happened and what you expected to happen instead. If you can, show us a sample board (make it a small one) and what happens to it when you call your function.

Comment: I have updated with a sample not so good looking output of what should happen.

Comment: I'm confused... `content` is a list of strings, and since `board` is the same as `content`, `board[rows][columns] = ...` should raise `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: That is what happens. I just wanted to know is there anything I can do to replace board[rows][columns] that have Os with Xs . Currently it gives the error you mentioned and the only I can replace anything at all is if I replace the entire board.

Comment: @user82996, If you're getting an exception, you should always mention it.

Comment: Sorry. I stayed up very late working on this and also my first time posting here. I'll keep that in mind next time I need help with something.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, however, just a couple of comments:

- To remove *any* number of `\n` characters from the end of a string you can just use

  `string = string.rstrip('\n')`
- On the line you use replace you are trying to perform the replacement on a single cell of your matrix (`board[rows][columns]`) and you are assigning the result of the replacement on that single cell to the whole matrix. I think what you meant was actually:

  `board[rows][columns] = board[rows][columns].replace('O', 'X'))`

EDIT: since your cells always contain either `'O'` or `'X'`, why not simply writing:

```
board[rows][columns] = 'X'
```

and

```
board[rows][columns] = 'O'
```

depending on the new character you want them to contain?

EDIT2:
Just as a side note, a more pythonic way to do the strip part would be:

```
content = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in content]
```

EDIT3: as I now understand your problem is that strings are immutable and I wrongly assumed you were working with lists of characters. To convert your board to a list of lists of characters (hence mutable), just do the following:

```
new_board = []
for line in board:
    new_line = [c for c in line]
    new_board.append(new_line)
```

Comment: yeah I updated my code with that :) but i am still unable to replace that specific cell. When I run it the cell doesn't actually get replaced :(

Comment: I edited my answer, I am not sure why you want to `replace()` instead of just overwriting the new character.

Comment: I tried what you said and it gives me the error: 'str' object does not support item assignment. Which is why I am trying to replace because python has a built in str.replace() method

Comment: Edited again, this should fix it. At this point `replace` should not work because it is a method of strings, while you are using lists of characters, but you should be able to do something along the lines of `board[i][j] = 'X'`.

Comment: I was trying to be lazy and just work without creating  a list. But I will try that. I think that'll make it a lot easier to work with the code.